# How to output json data in array using curl

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have code here that will get json data using curl. Now I want to echo all data. This will show no output.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('myurl');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
?>
```

This is json coming from my url:

```
 ({"Response_Code":"0000","ResultMobilePrefix":["0917","0905","0906","0915","0916","0926","0927","0937","0935","0817","0936","0922","0923",
"0932","0933","0934","0942","0943","0907","0908","0909","0910","0912","0918","0919","0920","
0921","0928","0929","0930","0938","0939","0948","0949","0925","0989","0999","0947","0998","
0946","0975","0977"]});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is
    echo json_encode($json);

Answer (score 0):

Use `true` to convert it into array;

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

for displaying json in format use `json_encode()` and for proper format use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get rid of the bracket and semicolon on the JSON file first before you can use the json_decode();

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('myurl');

    //remove the brackets
    $json = str_replace("(", "", $json);
    $json = str_replace(")", "", $json);

    //remove the semicolon
    $json = str_replace(";", "", $json);

    $data = json_decode($json);
    print_r($data);
?>
```

this is a bit ugly, but hope you get the idea, you need to remove that character first

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to what [Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029506/manish-jangir-blogaddition-com) has explained above. This is what PHP Docs say about the second parameter:

```
When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
```

else you will simply get a `stdclass` object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the URL does not return a valid Json

you could simply try

```
  var_dump($data);
```

this will return **null** because it's not a valid json see [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

this will work

```
 $json = file_get_contents('myurl');
 $json = preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}|[\t\n\r\(\)\;]/', '', trim($json));
 $data = json_decode($json);
 print_r($data);
```